# Firebase user authentication to all RTDBs

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have been struggling with database security rules for a while. Especially with auth manipulation, such as `".write": "auth.uid === $uid"`.

I realized today that Firebase SDK will only log the user within the default app's RTDB and, therefore, will not send authentication during other database exchanges.
Did I miss something during the authentication process for multiple databases?

Here are the firebase configuration :

```
firebaseConfig: {
    apiKey: "xxx",
    appId: "xxx"
    authDomain: "xxx",
    databaseURL: "https://my-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/",
    projectId: "xxx",
    storageBucket: "xxx",
    ...
  },
  firebaseAnotherConfig: {
    databaseURL: "https://another-rtdb-instance.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/",
    storageBucket: "xxx", // same as firebaseConfig
  },
  firebaseThelastConfig: {
    databaseURL: "https://the-last-rtdb-instance.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/",
    storageBucket: "xxx", // same as firebaseConfig
  }
```

Here the initializations

```
    initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    initializeApp(firebaseAnotherConfig, 'another');
    initializeApp(firebaseThelastConfig, 'thelast');
```

Then the auth management works through getAuh() function, so within the default app from "firebaseConfig".

All apps are initialized before auth.
All data exchanges are working fine with all databases.

Tests in google console are working fine in all databases.
But, for know, rtdb rules "auth.uid !== null" only works live with the default rtdb.

I noticed the following function in firebase/app retrieving all apps: "getApps()". But I couldn't make it work with Firebase "signin.." functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you sign in to Firebase Authentication, you're signed in to the entire **project** - not to a specific database.

If you want to connect to a different database than the one you included in the configuration data you passed to `initializeApp`, you can pass that database's URL to the [`getDatabase` call](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/database.md#getdatabase_d9cea01).

So for example:

```js
let app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
let db1 = getDatabase(app); // this gets you the configured database
let db2 = getDatabase(app, "url of other database");
```

Comment: Thank you Frank for your help !
I understand now that what I did was stupid.. 